# Why does Salesforce OAuth2 redirect me from one instance na3 for ex to another na9

Tags: salesforce, oauth-2.0

I am trying to build a web app that lets the customer add demo data to any Salesforce instance. My demo builder uses OAuth 2 Authorization Code Grant.

I am trying to get the switch instance portion working. However once the user connects to one instance

GET /services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=blabla.UKP&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsfblademo.bla.com%2Foauth%2Fcallback HTTP/1.1
Host: na9.salesforce.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.12 Safari/535.2
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: cookie_bla; disco=5:00D50000000Ii39:00550000001ifEp:0|; autocomplete=1; inst=APP5

It redirects to the previous instance. Seems like its reading cookies and redirecting

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: 
Location: https://na3.salesforce.com/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp?source=blablabla
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 525
Date: Fri, 16 Sep 2011 21:46:58 GMT

The URL has moved [here](https://na3.salesforce.com/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp?source=blablabla)

Is there a way to sign out or clear the cookies salesforce has. I am not running my app on salesforce.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The API logout() call isn't going to work because that will only invalidate the API session and not the UI session stored in the browser cookie on the `*.salesforce.com` domain, to which your app won't have direct access. That's not to say it isn't still recommended, but to clear that UI cookie, you'll need to redirect the end user to `/secur/logout.jsp` on the `instance_url` of the previous session. To make it transparent to end users, you can load it in a hidden iframe like this:

`<iframe src='https://{instance_url}/secur/logout.jsp' width='0' height='0' style='display:none;'></iframe>`

Comment: This is what I ended up doing but I feel that SF could still provide a programmatic way of doing this. Thanks for the help./

Answer (score 0):

Before switching to other instance, you can try making the logout call, as described here WS Guide :http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_logout.htm

This will invalidate the previous session hopefully..

Comment: I tried this, and it will only invalidate the API session, not the UI session in the browser cookie. See my answer about using logout.jsp as a workaround.